# WMS application in Apache

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, tomcat, apache

To host a map application in real world, developed using GeoServer, we need a server with Tomcat/JSP rather than Apache, right? Correct me if I am wrong since my background is as GIS not development. Is there any options to host GeoServer in Apache Server or any similar applications like GeoServer that can connect with an Apache server. Because to maintain a good Apache Server is economical compared to Tomcat.

Update:

In GeoServer, as localhost, if we login and check Server Status, Memory Usage shows 376 MB. Therefore, if we plan to hire a host plan in JSP/Tomcat, the heap size offered should be greater than 376 MB, isn't it?, which will escalate the server plan cost. Need help on this aspect.

Answer (score 7):

GeoServer is a Java web application packaged as a WAR file. It needs to be deployed in a Java servlet container of which Apache Tomcat is an implementation. You could also use another servlet engine like Jetty. So in order to use GeoServer, you will be obliged to use a Java servlet container.
If you want to avoid the use of a servlet engine, you could also use another OGC WMS compliant implementation like MapServer.